# Out of memory error java heap space using IOUtils.copyLarge . How can I fix this?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm, inputstream, java-io

I have an application (Springboot api) that runs un kubernetes and i have a single instance with `cpu:200m` and `memory:8Gi`. My jvm parameters are : `_JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx7G -Xms7G`
My goal is to copy one or more files of size between **30Mb** and **1Gb** from one s3 bucket to an other with presigned url.

I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error when i call my api more than 2 times in paralelle with 1 gb files.

Here is my code :

```
public ResponseEntity<String> transferData(Config config) throws IOException {

    var inputUrl = config.getInputdUrl();
    var outputUrl = config.getOutputdUrl();


    var uploadConnection = uploader.getUploadConnection(outputUrl);

    try (var inputStream = downloader.getDownloadConnection(inputUrl); 
         var outputStream = uploadConnection.getOutputStream()) {

        IOUtils.copyLarge(inputStream, outputStream);

        var resp = uploadConnection.getResponseCode();

        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body("Transfer done with response:" + resp);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .body("An  error occurred while transferring data : " + ioe);
    }

}
```

`getUploadConnection` return `HttpURLConnection` :

```java
        var connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(presignedUrl).openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod(PUT.toString());
        return connection;
```

`getDownloadConnection` return an `HttpURLConnection` inputStream.

```java
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(presignedUrl).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod(GET.toString());
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
return connection.getInputStream();
```

Regarding my code and my configuration, I though that the impact on memory would be less important as I stream the file and dont get it completly in memory.

What am i missing ?

EDIT 1:
I added `setChunkedStreamingMode` so now my `getUploadConnection` return :

```java
        var connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(-1);
        connection.setRequestMethod(PUT.toString());
        return connection;
```

But i get an `411` error from my s3 bucket

Comment: Make sure you're using chunked or fixed-length transfer mode.

Comment: What does your `getUploadConnection` look like? Make sure you set a chunk size on the URL connection, if not it will buffer internally instead of streaming it to the receiver.

Comment: It looks like that : 

        var connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(presignedUrl).openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod(PUT.toString());
        return connection;

How cani use chunked or fixed-length transfer mode ?

Comment: I should use chunked or fixed-length transfer mode for uploader and also downloader ?

Comment: `connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(8192)` or whatever large buffer size you want - not too large, or `connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode()` if you know the size in advance. I believe there is the same thing on `HttpServletResponse` but I haven't checked.

Comment: @user207421 i get a **411** response when I add `.setChunkedStreamingMode(8192)` to the HttpURLConnection that is respnsible of uploading the file

Comment: That's 'Content-length required'. So use fixed-length. Chunked doesn't send a Content-Length header, because each chunk has its own header. Fixed-length does send the header. If you don't use either of these, Java has to buffer up the entire output to determine the length so it can send the Content-Length ahead of the data.

Comment: The probleme is that i dont know in advance the size of the file. And if i want to know it, I will have to load it completly

Comment: Why? How are you acquiring the file?

Comment: I read the file from a Bucket S3 with a pre-signed-url and send it to an other S3 bucket also with a pre-signed-url.
So i dont know what is the size of the file in advance.

This is how i read my file : 

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(presignedUrl).openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod(GET.toString());
 connection.setDoOutput(true);
return connection.getInputStream();
````

Comment: So have a look at the Content-length: header on the input.

Comment: Why rely on some mythical 3rd party library function “`IOUtils.copyLarge`” whatever when you can simply use [`inputStream.transferTo(outputStream);`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo(java.io.OutputStream))?

Comment: Just call `getContentLengthLong()` on the input connection, to get the length for the output connection’s `setFixedLengthStreamingMode(…)`. If S3 doesn’t accept chunked transfer as input, it shouldn’t use chunked transfer for output either. So the content length of the input should be known.

Comment: You are right, I can simply use `inputStream.transferTo(outputStream)`.
It works with `setFixedLengthStreamingMode(…)`

I am now able to transfer many files without a big load in memory.

Comment: I just wonder why i have to do it for the upload connection and not for the download connection ...

Comment: The sender sets the transfer mode for the send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `setFixedLengthStreamingMode` set in my outPut connection, I was able to transfer more files without `Out of memory error java heap space` issues.

My output Connection :

```java
var connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(presignedUrl).openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(downloadConnection.getContentLengthLong());
```